# How to get the response data in ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a php file(index.php) with two fields when i post that form, in javascript i am doing form data serialize and send it to next php page(results.php) through ajax. When i try to print the data inside success it is not printing. FInd the below code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" name="index" id="indexform">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="sendData"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#indexform" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log( $(this).serialize() );
          var formdata = $(this).serialize();
         // alert(formdata);
          $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"result.php",
                dataType:'json',
                data:formdata,
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
          });
        });
    </script>
```

In the above i cant print the data inside the success callback.

Comment: What's the content of result.php?

Comment: Can you show the result.php page

Comment: @James I am just printing some $_REQUEST in result.php

Comment: just put <?php echo "sample"; exit;?> first line on your result.php

Comment: @Nathan i am already just doing some echo as you said but i didnt see anything.

Comment: I think the problem is that you specified json as the response, set dataType: 'text' and see if you get the alert, also check your browser console for any errors

Comment: If i change the dataType as text i am getting the alert value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( "#indexform" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
              event.preventDefault();
              console.log( $(this).serialize() );
              var formdata = $(this).serialize();
              $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"result.php",
                    data:formdata,
                    success: function(html){
                        alert(html);
                    }
              });
            });
        </script>
```

In your result.php page

```
 $name=$_REQUEST['fname'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    echo $name." ".$email;
```

Comment: @krrr25 are you try this

Comment: if i change dataType its getting form value.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the [`dataType`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to `json` so you must ensure that you only return valid json.

That means you cannot `echo` or `print` whatever you want; you should collect your data in an array or object and then only once output that like:

```
echo json_encode($your_data);
```

Comment: how can i get the response value inside php

Comment: @krrr25 You should post your php script here.

Answer (score 0):

Echo the content inside results.php page.

Ex:

```
echo "two fields $first_field , $second_field  successfully inserted. " ;
```

This content results as an ajax response and stores in the data variable .

Answer (score 0):

Hello My Friends your html code is in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#indexform" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          console.log( $(this).serialize() );
          var formdata = $(this).serialize();
         // alert(formdata);
          $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"result.php",
                dataType:'json',
                data:formdata,
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
          });
        });
    </script>
```

and you result.php file code is in

```
<?php
    include 'db.php';
    $name=$_REQUEST['fname'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    echo $name." ".$email;
?>
```

now the result.php file is return the entered name and email address.